# Same order different shipping address for each shipment

Tags: magento2, shipping

I am creating shipments programmatically for an order. The order has 3 shipments, I need each shipment to go to a different address.

The order has same product in qty 3. So each item(qty:1) needs to go to a different address but I am unable to change the address for the shipment. Here's what I've tried so far -

```
    $shippingAddressId = $this->order->getShippingAddress()->getId();

    $address = $this->addressRepository->get($shippingAddressId);

    $anotherAddress = $this->addressRepository->get(6);

    $address->setCountryId($anotherAddress->getCountryId());
    $address->setRegion($anotherAddress->getRegion());
    $address->setPostcode($anotherAddress->getPostcode());
    $address->setStreet($anotherAddress->getStreet());
    $address->setCity($anotherAddress->getCity());
    $address->save();

    $shipment->setShippingAddressId($shippingAddressId);
    return;
```

Thanks!

Comment: We should use the multi address shipping checkout logic. For your case, we should create separate orders for each shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to Stores => Configuration (under Settings)

Step 2: Expand Sales tab from the left sidebar on the Configuration page. Click on Multishipping Settings.

Step 3: Uncheck the Use System Value box and configure the following settings:

Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses: Set this option to “Yes” to enable multishipping on your store.

Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses: Specify a limit to the number of products you want to ship when a customer uses multishipping option.

Step 4: Click on Save Config button.

You’ll be prompted to refresh invalidated cache types through a system pop-up message.

Your customers can now choose different shipping addresses in an order during the checkout process.

When a customer clicks on Check Out with Multiple Addresses button, they are requested to select the shipping address for each item in the cart.